# How to implement an offline form in Angular?

Tags: angular, caching, service-worker, angular-service-worker, cacheapi

I am trying to implement an Angular form on my website where a user will enter data when they are offline and it will automatically be saved in the backend when the user comes online.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-local-storage

Comment: https://medium.com/@tiagovalverde/how-to-save-your-app-state-in-localstorage-with-angular-ce3f49362e31